# Can spells creating extradimensional spaces be cast in Ravenloft?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes

If Ravenloft is a demiplane, and a demiplane is an extradimensional space, can spells that create extradimensional spaces (like *rope trick*) be cast while in the realm?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. This is a good question that I feared might get downvotes for reasons unrelated to content, so I edited it. I hope that's okay; feel free to edit it further or roll it back. Thank you for participating and have fun.

Comment: As a tiny nitpick, do you mean Barovia or Ravenloft?

Comment: @nitsua60 Am I right in thinking the nitpick here is that Ravenloft is the setting name OoC and the castle in-game, and Barovia is the name of the actual plane (aka the Demiplane of Dread)?

Comment: @SirTechSpec yup; thus the nitpick would be to clarify whether OP means "can I do this in the castle?" vs. "can I do this anywhere in Barovia."  Either way, the first sentence of OP clearly has a teeny-tiny error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes you can,

Spoilers for rules not plot ahead...

Page 24 in Curse of Strahd indicates the specifics but the properties of the Demiplane of Dread (Barovia/Ravenloft) indicates that such extradimensional constructs as created via Demiplane or Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion are subject to the same warping rules as found in Barovia. Thus you could indeed "camp" in a Rope Trick but can't then Planeshift out of that to escape Barovia whereas normally you could planeshift out of such things as Demiplane spells if you were on nearly any other plane.

> No spell - not even wish -- allows one to escape from Strahd's domain.
>  Astral Projection, teleport, plane shift, and similar spells cast for
>  the purpose of leaving Barovia simply fail...

Then a bit later...

> Magic that summons creatures or objects from other planes functions
>  normally in Barovia, as does magic that involves an extradimensional
>  space. Any spells cast within such an extradimensional space (such as
>  that created by Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion ) **are subject to
>  the same restrictions as magic cast in Barovia.** --Curse of Strahd
>  P24 Alterations to Magic

Answer (score 17):

Yes.

> The Mad Mage of Mount Baratok has *Mordenkainen's magnificent mansion* prepared and can successfully cast it.

The demiplane created by a spell like *Mordenkainen's magnificent mansion* (PHB. p. 261) still follows the same rules regarding planar travel, so while you can create and enter an extradimensional space, you can't then planeshift out of that extradimensional space to escape.

Comment: I edited this to cite a source but to preserve the spoiler.  By using an example I think I preserved your meaning. If not, please feel free to revert or otherwise edit the answer again. (and a +1 from me).

Answer (score -2):

Is there any reason why you think it can't?

Rope Trick says:

> At the 
>   upper end of the rope, an invisible entrance opens to an 
>   extradimensional space that lasts until the spell ends.

There is no reason if, having entered that extradimensional space, that I couldn't cast rope trick *again* and climb into a different extradimensional space.

Since the DMG says of Demiplanes

> Demiplanes are extradimensional spaces ...

The same would apply.

Technically, all planes are "extradimensional spaces" the difference between Demi- and non Demi- one's is that the former are finite and the latter are infinite.

Comment: Yes, there is. It's like putting a bag of holding inside a portable hole: you can't put an extradimensional space inside another extradimensional space.

Comment: @Benubird is there some general rule about demiplanes you're thinking of there? I don't see anything at DMG p.68 "Demiplanes" that would make me think *all* extradimensional spaces come with the nesting risk that is mentioned in the descriptions of *portable hole*, *handy haversack*, and *bag of holding.* Those descriptions mention "similar items," but don't mention other extradimensional spaces created by spells.

Comment: @nitsua60 you're right, I just interpret "similar items" as meaning "anything that has a similar effect", and assume that all extradimensional spaces have the same risks. I consider that "extradimensional" describes a metaphysical existence outside of any plane or dimension, and therefore you can't enter or exit it except via the built-in entrance. As DM, you could treat demiplanes as small planes rather than extradimensional spaces, but I do think the implication is that demiplanes are like big bags of holding.

Comment: For me the key is "items"; in the PH/HH/BoH descriptions we're warned of the risks inherent with *items* that create extra space. Perhaps I'm focusing too tightly on that, but it seems to be a qualitative difference between a magically-created item adn a (?)-created demiplane. (Otherwise, what distinction is being drawn between an extradimensional space and a demiplane? I'm going to be naturally suspicious of an interpretation that removes any differences between things described by two different terms.)